# Timer that can be used in JVM Scala & Scala.js

Tags: java, scala, timer, scala.js

At the moment I am working on a project that is cross-compiled to [Scala.js](https://www.scala-js.org/) and normal JVM Scala. Now I need to implement a timer (for reconnecting a websocket) that triggers a function every x seconds. What would be a good implementation of such a timer that can be cross compiled?

As far as I know I cannot use e.g.:

- `java.util.concurrent` (doesn't compile to Scala.js)
- `setTimeout` and `setInterval` (javascript - not usable from JVM Scala)

Is there any good alternative or am I wrong and these can be used?

Comment: You could use [`cats.effect.Timer[IO]`](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/timer.html). If you also use [`IOApp`](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/ioapp.html) it will be **implicitly** injected in the application start, both for JVM and JS.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this cats class yet. Thanks a lot. Since the application isn't written in a functional manner, I ended up using `java.util.Timer`, but I'll definetly keep this in mind for other projects. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`java.util.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) is supported by Scala.js, and provides exactly the functionality you're describing:

```scala
val x: Long = seconds
val timer = new java.util.Timer()
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new java.util.TimerTask {
  def run(): Unit = {
    // this will be executed every x seconds
  }
}, 0L, x * 1000L)
```

Consult the JavaDoc that I linked above for details about the API.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.